# Error al hacer click en items de recyclerView

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy haciendo un `NavigationDrawer`, por lo que para los items utilizo recyclerView, y cuando hago click en uno de los items obtengo el siguiente error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams

```
public class ActivityPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Item> itemsNavDrawerList;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListPositionDecoration;

    private void cargarMenu() {
    itemsNavDrawerList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayListPositionDecoration = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < preferencesRolesUsuario.getAll().size(); i++){
        rol = encryption.decryptOrNull(preferencesRolesUsuario.getString(encryption.encryptOrNull(String.valueOf(i + 1)), null));
        switch (rol){
                case "Invitado":
                    itemsNavDrawerList.add(new Item(0, "INICIO", R.drawable.ic_home_tea700_20dp, "Inicio", getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.tea800), R.drawable.item_navdrawer_focus_on, false));
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemsNavDrawerList);
    binding.recyclerViewItemNavigationDrawer.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    itemAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String id = itemsNavDrawerList.get(binding.recyclerViewItemNavigationDrawer.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getIdItem();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: El problema esta en la declaración de esta variable itemsNavDrawerList ( no la has compartido en el código)

Comment: lo unico que me falta de la variable itemsNavDrawerList es su declaracion, la cual la hize fuera del metodo cargarMenu(). ¿Que puede estar mal de esta variable?(Codigo actualizado).

Comment: Revisa el tipo de ítem que empleas en la vista, la librería que importas, y el método que utilizas, el error dice que intentas usar o castear una vista que no corresponde a la variable empleada.